# On Mountain Lion, Trash doesn't Empty

Tags: macos, trash

there is a file stuck in the trash

[image]

This is what it shows when i do 'Get Info'

[image]

When i 'Empty' the trash

[image]

The sound plays, the trash window disappears, but the Trash icon doesn't appear empty and the file is still there when i reopen the trash. [image]
[image]

I've tried the terminal [image]

According to the terminal, there is no file in the Trash folder. 
What am i missing? How can i solve this?

**EDIT**
So, i found out that the file is actually in another volume and as the Trash shows the 'trash' for all volumes, the file is being shown in the trash.

So, the file is in the Trash for my Bootcamp volume [/Volumes/BOOTCAMP/.Trashes/501]

I try deleting it from the terminal
[image]

but its still there [image]

what do i do?

Comment: Did you try rebooting ?

Comment: yes, i did try to reboot. Doesn't fix the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Trash contains files from different volumes. Try running…

```
rm -rfv /Volumes/BOOTCAMP/.Trashes/*
```

Depending on drive permissions, this may have to be run using `sudo`.

Comment: +1, i did have to use 'sudo', but the file is still there (even though the 'rm' command doesn't show any error message, or a success message either)

Comment: Isn't NTFS read-only on Mac (unless you have a third-party driver installed)?

Answer (score 3):

One simple idea first: hold down the option (alt) key as you choose Finder > Empty Trash (see Apple's [HT1526](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1526?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)).

If that doesn't work, I noticed that if you look closely in your Get Info screenshot, you can see that the file is actually in /Volumes/BOOTCAMP/.Trashes/501, not ~/.Trash.

I'd try `rm -f /Volumes/BOOTCAMP/.Trashes/501/2.Broke.Girls.S02E19.HDTV.XvID-AFG`

Comment: that's what i was missing. So, now i know where the file is. I can see it with ls. but when i try to delete it with 'rm -f', the terminal shows no error or success message, and the file is still there. What is wrong?

Comment: Can you post the results from `ls -al` in that directory, and also `id` (so we can see your user ID for comparison)?